# How can I configure Vim for 2 different languages?

Tags: ruby, vim, indentation, file-type, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am currently using Vim for Python, and would like to start using it while I learn Ruby too.

Is there a way to configure the vimrc file so that different settings apply depending on the filetype currently being worked on?

For example, my vimrc is currently set to have an indentation of 4 spaces, which I would like to be 2 spaces for Ruby files.  Additionally, I would like the syntax Ruby syntax highlighting to be on when working on ruby files, and Python syntax highlighting for python files.

I stumbled across this for defining the tab spaces:

```
autocmd FileType python set tabstop=8|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab
autocmd FileType ruby set tabstop=8|set shiftwidth=2|set expandtab
```

Is there something similar for syntax highlighting?

Comment: Syntax highlighting should be working using factory settings. Try moving your .vimrc out of the way to check that, and possibly copy the stock `/usr/share/vim/vim74/vimrc_example.vim` to `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 6):

**First,**

make sure you have the following lines somewhere near the top of your `vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

**Second,**

this snippet is technically correct:

```
autocmd FileType python set tabstop=8|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab
autocmd FileType ruby set tabstop=8|set shiftwidth=2|set expandtab
```

but it could be made:

- simpler and more readable by removing the bars and the redundant `set`s,
- safer by changing the remaining ones to `setlocal` in order to limit your options to the targeted buffer:

  ```
  autocmd FileType python setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
  autocmd FileType ruby   setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
  ```

**Third,**

those autocommands don't replace themselves when you re-source your `vimrc`: they will just pile up, and up, and up… until your Vim becomes unbearably slow and unresponsive.

If you insist on keeping those settings in your `vimrc` it would be wise to use the pattern described by Cody in his answer:

```
augroup python
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
augroup END

augroup ruby
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType ruby setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
augroup END
```

**Fourth,**

Vim's filetype detection mechanism already does most of the work for you by looking for `ftplugin/python.vim` and `after/ftplugin/python.vim` in `&runtimepath` each time the `FileType` event is triggered with the value `python`… which makes adding `FileType` autocommands to your `vimrc` largely redundant.

Keep your `vimrc` lean and clean by creating the file `after/ftplugin/python.vim` with this content:

```
 setlocal tabstop=8
 setlocal shiftwidth=4
 setlocal expandtab
```

and so on for ruby and other filetypes…

Note: use `ftplugin/python.vim` if you want to completely override the default python filetype plugin and `after/ftplugin/python.vim` if you only want to add/change a few things.

Note: paths are relative to `~/.vim` on unix-like systems and `%userprofile%\vimfiles` on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, very helpful.

Comment: Note that while #1-#3 is good to know, #4 is what you should really pay attention to.

Answer (score 1):

```
augroup ruby
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType ruby set tabstop=8|set shiftwidth=2|set expandtab
  ... Any other ruby specific settings
augroup END

augroup python
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType python set tabstop=8|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab
  ... Any other python specific settings
augroup END
```

In the case of syntax highlighting, it should be happening automatically. If vim isn't detecting the file type for you, `:setf ruby` or `:setf python` should work while you're in the file.

Comment: The autocmd! removes all autocommands for the group, so you don't get pollution if you reload your .vimrc.

Comment: `:h autocmd` will give you more information in Vim.

Comment: Thanks for the info, helps a bunch!